# How to replace values in a array?

Tags: python

I'm beggining to study python and saw this:

I have and array(km_media) that have nan values,

```
km_media = km / (2019 - year)
```

it happend because the variable year has some 2019.

So for the sake of learning, I would like to know how do to 2 things:

1. how can I use the replace() to substitute the nan values for 0 in the variable;
2. how can i print the variable that has the nan values with the replace.

What I have until now:

1.

```
km_media = km_media.replace('nan', 0)
```

2. 

```
print(f'{km_media.replace('nan',0)}')
```

Thanks

Comment: Please show a [mcve] to illustrate what you are asking about. Technically, Python has lists, not arrays, unless you are using a third-party library such as numpy. If you are using numpy, be sure to add it to the tags.

Comment: `NaN` is not equal to anything, including another `NaN`..

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Python most certainly [has arrays](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) but I agree that the OP should clarify the question.

Comment: if the var year has 2019 then you will end up with inf not nan

Comment: @Selcuk Yah, I could have worded my comment better. I was trying to clarify what the OP means by "array" to make sure we are talking about the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure is this will do what you are looking for?

```
a = 2 / np.arange(5)
print(a)
array([       inf, 2.        , 1.        , 0.66666667, 0.5       ])


b = [i if i != np.inf or i != np.nan else 0 for i in a]
print(b)

Output:
[0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.6666666666666666, 0.5]
```

Or:

```
np.where(((a == np.inf) | (a == np.nan)), 0, a)
```

Or:

```
a[np.isinf(a)] = 0
```

Also, for part 2 of your question, I'm not sure what you mean. If you have just replaced the inf's with 0, then you will just be printing zeros. If you want the index position of the inf's you have replaced, you can grab them before replacement:

```
np.where(a == np.inf)[0][0]

Output:
0  # this is the index position of np.inf in array a
```